# Navigation bar out of two UL- parts with CSS

Tags: css

just started learning CSS and am facing a problem.

My problem is that I try to make a navigation bar on top of the homepage with a picture below it, the navigation bar consists of 2 UL-parts, one on the left side, second on the right side. Problem is the picture and the text (H1- header) is starting from a wrong place, when they should (or what Im trying to achieve in here) start from the end of the "row" named DIV-element.

HTML one:

```
<div class="row">
    <ul id="left">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
       <li>3</li>
       <li>4</li>
       <li>5</li>
   </ul>

   <ul id="right">
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div class="picture">
    <h1>This header is going in wrong place.</h1>
    <p>This is where the text comes.</p>
</div>
```

CSS one:

```
.row ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.row li {
    display: inline
}

.row #left {
    float: left;
}

.row #right {
    float: right;
}

.picture {
      background-image:url('http://goo.gl/04j7Nn');
    height: 400px;
}
```

Here's a link: http://jsfiddle.net/yw8uZ/109/

Any suggestions how could I do this or how I could make this work? Thanks!

Comment: Since you are learning, I suggest you try to also get yourself in the habit of following best practices when it comes to your ids and classes. `.row` is highly generic, even for a class, and a navbar really should have an id since it is a major and unique element on the page (usually), while `#left` and `#right` could easily be reused and should be classes (and even there `.float-left` may be better).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css :

`.row{
    display:block;
    height:20px;
}`

Your `row` class has no attributes such as height, spacing etc..

So when the next element comes along it just throws it wheverever it can! :)

Im not sure if you want the text over the image, but if not you will need to take that HTML element out of the `picture` class scope.

Comment: No problem at all, well asked question so was easy to asnwer! Good luck with the CSS learning!

Comment: It's not wrong, per se, but giving `display: block `to `.row `is redundant here as it is a `div` and those are block elements by default. If the row class is reused with some element that is not, this could lead to unexpected or confusing behavior (assuming that the non-block element was intentionally chosen for its non-block status)